# Is there any way for synchronisation the system clock

Tags: android, time

Logcat

```
12-06 09:23:25.693: W/System.err(537): 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
```

'system clock in sync' this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you haven't `root`ed your phone and your provider doesn't provide [NITZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NITZ), you're kind of screwed if your phone doesn't keep good time or doesn't sync to GPS time.